# CSS div inside div extend bottom

Tags: css

```css
div.div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

div.div2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">Test123</div>
</div>
```

I have the above code that gives a 400x100 div with another one in it. The second is 10pixels next to top, left and right side of the first one, which is fine but I want to extend it so it's aso 10 pixels from bottom... How can I fix this?

Comment: if it's a fixed height outer, why not just give the inner a height of 80px; (and add box-sizing:border-box to it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here is your solution .

```css
div.div1 {
 border: 1px solid red;
color: red;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
}

div.div2 {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">Test123</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this? Child `<div>` is never following it's parent in heights as it is doing for width. So if you want to have something be equally distant from it's parent you have two choices, either the code bellow, or fixing the height of the child too, and then, by using `javascript` make it bigger.

```css
div.div1 {
      border: 1px solid red;
      color: red;
      width: 400px;
    }
    
    div.div2 {
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 


    <div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
        Test123 <br/>
        Test123 <br/>
        Test123 <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
```